# Value error as I try to take the dot product of 2 matrices

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to take the dot product of 2 Sobel outputs.

```
car_img = cv2.imread("car.png")

ix = cv2.Sobel(car_img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize = ksize, scale = scale)
iy = cv2.Sobel(car_img, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize = ksize, scale = scale)
```

As I try to take their dot product like:

```
np.dot(ix, iy)
```

I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: shapes (240,320,3) and (240,320,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 2) != 320 (dim 1)
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: By "dot product", do you mean the elementwise (Hadamard) product?

Comment: @MarcusLim Dot product between 2 matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.dot()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) does matrix multiplication if you are dealing with 2-D arrays. So your code is trying to multiply two `m x n` matrices, which is undefined when `m != n`. Something like `np.dot(ix, np.transpose(iy))` - that is, multiplying matrix `ix` by the [transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) of `iy`, *would* be defined, for example, because the latter would be an `n x m` matrix.

Comment: Each matrix has a shape of `(240,320,3)`. How could I take a dot product of these 2 matrices?

Comment: The [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) is an operation on vectors, not matrices. Are you thinking of [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to calculate the value of `v` as given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method#Concept . The formula taken from this link: https://ibb.co/wYLxNST

Comment: I have `ix` and `iy`. Now I want to compute `A`  as given in the above link to compute `v`

Comment: I have no idea how to correctly implement Lucas-Kanade - if that is what you're trying to do, I would update your question to ask this directly, now that you know the answer to your initial question ... but is there a reason you are trying to implement this yourself, rather than just using the built-in OpenCV version? --> https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html

Comment: Wanted to understand the method. Therefore was trying to implement it. One thing that is confusing me is how to represent `A`. I have `ix` and `iy`. How can I write this as `A`? As also given in the link I shared, `A` is represented as https://ibb.co/H2cpxY0 Initially I thought, it could be represented as a dot product but now I don't think so

Comment: Do you have any idea on could I represent `A` ?

Comment: https://sandipanweb.wordpress.com/2018/02/25/implementing-lucas-kanade-optical-flow-algorithm-in-python/

Comment: I had checked this link but I am trying to implement what Wikipedia method says

Comment: It might be nice to amend this answer to summarize these comments.  Apparently `dot` (matrix product) is the wrong operation for what the OP wants.